# what is the default delimiter for sort -k option

Tags: sort

What is the default delimiter for `sort`'s `-k` option? I searched some man page and samples and still feel lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GNU `sort`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation) documentation for the `-t` option says

> By default, fields are separated by the empty string between a non-blank character and a blank character. By default a blank is a space or a tab, but the LC_CTYPE locale can change this.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) says

> If **-t** is not specified, <blank> characters shall be used as default field separators; each maximal non-empty sequence of <blank> characters that follows a non- <blank> shall be a field separator.

Both amount to the same thing: by default, any sequence of whitespace characters separate fields, and the whitespace characters are part of the (following) field.

Thus

```
  foo  bar
```

(with two spaces at the beginning) is treated by `sort` as containing two fields,

```
  foo
```

and

```
  bar
```

(again with two spaces at the beginning).